# Can I solve a differential equation with the (ir)regular Coulomb wavefunctions?

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, special-functions, version-13

When I evaluate

```
  DSolve[w''[ρ]] + (1 - (2 η)/ρ) w[ρ] == 0, w[ρ], ρ]
```

Mathematica returns me a solution in terms of the Hypergeometric1F1 and HypergeometricU functions, but the solution to this equation is also a linear combination of the CoulombF[0, η, ρ] and CoulombG[0, η, ρ] functions (now implemented in the library).

How can I force Mathematica to give me the solution to the above differential equation in term of the (ir)regular Coulomb wavefunctions F and G instead of the confluent hypergeometric functions U and 1F1?

Comment: fyi, Maple gives the solution in terms of Whittaker special functions $y \left(\rho \right) = 
c_{1} M_{i \eta ,\frac{1}{2}}\left(2 i \rho \right)+c_{2} W_{i \eta ,\frac{1}{2}}\left(2 i \rho \right)$ screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by9LB.png)

Comment: `CoulombF` and `CoulombG` are new in v13.0. They do not appear to be fully integrated. For example, `Entity["MathematicalFunction", #]["Dataset"]& /@ {"CoulombF", "CoulombG"}` have no entries.